# listview setOnClickListener returning wrong data from listview

Tags: android, listview

hi i am using avocarrot sdk for native ads. i have successfully implemented in my listview & ads are showing very well. but when i click on listview listitem using setOnClickListener i get wrong data. below is my code..

avocarrot setlistadapter

```
avocarrotInstream = new com.avocarrot.androidsdk.AvocarrotInstream(
            listAdapter,      /* pass your listAdapter */
            this,                   /* reference to your Activity */
            "my api key",       /* replace with your Avocarrot API Key */
            "my placement key"  /* replace with your Avocarrot Placement Key */
    );
    avocarrotInstream.setLogger(true, "ALL");
    avocarrotInstream.setSandbox(true);

    avocarrotInstream.setLayout(R.layout.avocarrot_feed_row, R.id.avo_container, R.id.feed_title,         R.id.feed_description, R.id.feed_icon, R.id.feed_image, R.id.feed_button);

    // Bind the created avocarrotInstream adapter to your list instead of your listAdapter
    listView.setAdapter(avocarrotInstream);
```

my onclicklistener

```
private class Click2 implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        Object obj = avocarrotInstream.getItem(position);
        String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText()
                .toString();
        String status = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtStatusMsg))
                .getText().toString();

        String bitmap = ((FeedItem) feedItems.get(position)).getImge();
        Intent in = new Intent(NewBlogStyleHindi.this, SingleActivity.class);
        in.setType("text/html");
        in.putExtra(TAG_TITLE, name);
        in.putExtra("images", bitmap);
        in.putExtra(TAG_TEXT, status);
        startActivity(in);
    }
}
```

and avocarrot provided there listview setonclicklistener as

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
      /* get your object from avocarrotInstream for clicked position */
      Object obj = avocarrotInstream.getItem(position);
    }
  });
```

due to ads row are increasing ..

Comment: Why are you not using `listView.setOnItemClickListener(new Click2());`?

Comment: thats what i am using but due to native ads row increasing so i get data one listitem back..if there a two ads in whole feed data then i get two listitem data back using setOnClickListener
can you tell me how to access listview data using this line
Object obj = avocarrotInstream.getItem(position);

Comment: Is there an error on that line? I don't see why that wouldn't work.

Comment: there is no error in logcat and i said it is working very well...the thing is first row is feed second row is ads then feed row then feed row then ad...so when i click very first row i get correct data using onclicklistener but after ad when i click on row i get one row ahead data due to row increased by ads..

Comment: I can read the question, there is no need to repost the code in the comments (which you shouldn't do for more than simple snippets). And you are already accessing the data in the listView. If the ads affect the data, then you should reconsider how you are storing the data.

Comment: is there anyone who actually can help me out...i am storing data perfectly..due to ads it just giving me next ImageView for current row..using setonclicklistener..

Comment: Use `getItem(position-1)`, then

Comment: thank you..i did that but for first row it show error because row staring form 0..after first ads it show image perfectly due to row increased by first ad..but after second ad it agan showing wrong image due to now two ads row increased

Comment: do you know how can i use this ..to get correct image..what avocarrot have given me 
Object obj = avocarrotInstream.getItem(position);

Comment: I have never used avocarrot, so no, I, personally, can't help, sorry

Answer (score 3):

This is Nikos from Avocarrot Support Team.

I think you have already contact us with our support service, but I post here an answer just in case someone else have a similar problem.

In your OnItemClickListener you must use the object from Avocarrot Adapter, not to access your object directly from your ArrayList.

So in your case :

```
Object obj = avocarrotInstream.getItem(position);
```

will return the FeedItem in correct position and the OnItemListener will change to :

```
private class Click2 implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    FeedItem feed = (FeedItem) avocarrotInstream.getItem(position);
    String name = feed.getName();
    String status = feed.getStatus();
    String bitmap = feed.getImge();
    Intent in = new Intent(NewBlogStyleHindi.this, SingleActivity.class);
    in.setType("text/html");
    in.putExtra(TAG_TITLE, name);
    in.putExtra("images", bitmap);
    in.putExtra(TAG_TEXT, status);
    startActivity(in);

    }
}
```